# Can I use balance_update at block to confirm account tezos change is valid?

Tags: rpc, operation

In the return result of rpc `/chains/main/blocks/321432`, there are many `balance_updates` field, should I use this field to judge one address tezos banlance change? And how can I confirm this block is not be rollback? And in the transaction `op2NTKLNP2Fj2kt6cpgh3DYZPhDdKMVoKDtTy37Y5YQA5h4L9FH`, I find a solitary `balance_updates` `"balance_updates": [
                  {
                    "kind": "contract",
                    "contract": "tz1LQNzUuGadrPbTqdafAxZCQc2zqRkENGob",
                    "change": "-181000"
                  }
                ]`
And other `balance_updatese` are in pairs, why this stand alone?

```
{
        "protocol": "PsBabyM1eUXZseaJdmXFApDSBqj8YBfwELoxZHHW77EMcAbbwAS",
        "chain_id": "NetXUdfLh6Gm88t",
        "hash": "op2NTKLNP2Fj2kt6cpgh3DYZPhDdKMVoKDtTy37Y5YQA5h4L9FH",
        "branch": "BLjQgCudh6rutT7Hu1sbzKC3B3iQ1Xd4Uxf88hXdWFZH7rgNgFo",
        "contents": [
          {
            "kind": "transaction",
            "source": "tz1LQNzUuGadrPbTqdafAxZCQc2zqRkENGob",
            "fee": "7575",
            "counter": "463039",
            "gas_limit": "70383",
            "storage_limit": "201",
            "amount": "0",
            "destination": "KT1TPBnfPq7XpCjL11HTzAeBkyxrSxUuskS9",
            "parameters": {
              "entrypoint": "default",
              "value": {
                "prim": "Pair",
                "args": [
                  {
                    "prim": "Pair",
                    "args": [
                      {
                        "prim": "Pair",
                        "args": [
                          {
                            "int": "1200000"
                          },
                          [
                            {
                              "string": "edsigteSbYS1LWAJue2RhoczKG8C48imf8Nag1bxrifqr1yAteYencA6BfwMgud1A8Z76iG2YSqQxMUXiXXMCNtNkYQvRzzsSFV"
                            },
                            {
                              "string": "edsigtrVeUQqMs9Uw8QuwNHJb37yKZA1BsnwtRxbyXF7KAQzf3CbrCuXbgLpG1pbZzeK7HTrPTPhfe3pKUGoDkAo7Aczd6GKCwX"
                            }
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "string": "tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "string": "123123123"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "metadata": {
              "balance_updates": [
                {
                  "kind": "contract",
                  "contract": "tz1LQNzUuGadrPbTqdafAxZCQc2zqRkENGob",
                  "change": "-7575"
                },
                {
                  "kind": "freezer",
                  "category": "fees",
                  "delegate": "tz1eY5Aqa1kXDFoiebL28emyXFoneAoVg1zh",
                  "cycle": 156,
                  "change": "7575"
                }
              ],
              "operation_result": {
                "status": "applied",
                "storage": {
                  "prim": "Pair",
                  "args": [
                    {
                      "prim": "Pair",
                      "args": [
                        [
                          {
                            "bytes": "005e1dedba2ecebc806006f94825fbc30ad173227c9db063545dc649fcc6fa13f9"
                          },
                          {
                            "bytes": "00590c1a5d9b532051087dacee8bf3c26213be94beeed8f08d0c3717d636a458f8"
                          },
                          {
                            "bytes": "007d0e8b580c5c7e9a7122e06251e8f24a18a3dea6c5e1c1f0747ea8ffdd390dc2"
                          }
                        ],
                        {
                          "int": "2"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    [
                      {
                        "prim": "Elt",
                        "args": [
                          {
                            "string": "000"
                          },
                          {
                            "prim": "Pair",
                            "args": [
                              {
                                "prim": "Pair",
                                "args": [
                                  {
                                    "prim": "Pair",
                                    "args": [
                                      {
                                        "prim": "Pair",
                                        "args": [
                                          {
                                            "int": "0"
                                          },
                                          {
                                            "bytes": "00"
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      [
                                        {
                                          "bytes": "001d7849f8eececf0896b97a632ef349d34bca0a9c"
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "bytes": "00001d7849f8eececf0896b97a632ef349d34bca0a9c"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "string": "000"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "prim": "Elt",
                        "args": [
                          {
                            "string": "123123123"
                          },
                          {
                            "prim": "Pair",
                            "args": [
                              {
                                "prim": "Pair",
                                "args": [
                                  {
                                    "prim": "Pair",
                                    "args": [
                                      {
                                        "prim": "Pair",
                                        "args": [
                                          {
                                            "int": "1200000"
                                          },
                                          {
                                            "bytes": "050100000009313233313233313233050a0000001600007906bec05de5c0bbaf5f6062fc33096ec29e9f30050080be9201"
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      [
                                        {
                                          "bytes": "002e7546bdd700ce86aed127c5b7d750e02cc27096"
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "bytes": "006fd838150bf6bf0e841913fb16bfd7430f0210db"
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "bytes": "00007906bec05de5c0bbaf5f6062fc33096ec29e9f30"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "string": "123123123"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "balance_updates": [
                  {
                    "kind": "contract",
                    "contract": "tz1LQNzUuGadrPbTqdafAxZCQc2zqRkENGob",
                    "change": "-181000"
                  }
                ],
                "consumed_gas": "60076",
                "storage_size": "1433",
                "paid_storage_size_diff": "181"
              },
              "internal_operation_results": [
                {
                  "kind": "transaction",
                  "source": "KT1TPBnfPq7XpCjL11HTzAeBkyxrSxUuskS9",
                  "nonce": 0,
                  "amount": "1200000",
                  "destination": "tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi",
                  "result": {
                    "status": "applied",
                    "balance_updates": [
                      {
                        "kind": "contract",
                        "contract": "KT1TPBnfPq7XpCjL11HTzAeBkyxrSxUuskS9",
                        "change": "-1200000"
                      },
                      {
                        "kind": "contract",
                        "contract": "tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi",
                        "change": "1200000"
                      }
                    ],
                    "consumed_gas": "10207"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "signature": "sigUYyTj3jWNtC6eHnnvMjZKTGt1MwMmzBbKHziYj5X4us7t6rX8s57MNkUGpMqqSs9p2kKFgqEi3KRd91SurgYpuYeSTrWr"
      }
```

Comment: Which network is this operation in ?

Answer (score 0):

This operation sits on babylonnet first of all (it is important that you mention which network to look at when you ask questions)

https://babylon.tzkt.io/op2NTKLNP2Fj2kt6cpgh3DYZPhDdKMVoKDtTy37Y5YQA5h4L9FH/463039

Now as you can see the contract call incurred 181 mutez of storage fees which are burned. So no one receives that fee.